# the parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied c#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview, parameters

I'm trying to build an application for a fictional music store, but I keep getting this on the `@Voornaamklant` and `@Achternaamklant`:

> parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied

I am retrieving the data from my `dataGridView2`, which gets its values from another `dataGridView` and a few `TextBoxes`. Then what I want to do here is to store everything in `dataGridView2` into my database table 'Factuur'.

I have 9 rows in my `dataGridView2` and all 9 are coming through in my database correctly. However, I have 10 rows in my table since my first column is an ID Auto_Incremented field, maybe that's something? I dont really think that is causing it though.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NieuwefactuurV2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void afsluitenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
            Titel.Text = dr.Cells["titelDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
            Prijs.Text = dr.Cells["prijsDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void Aantal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                double a = Convert.ToDouble(Aantal.Text);
                double b = Convert.ToDouble(Prijs.Text);

                Subtotaal.Text = (a * b).ToString();
            }

            catch
            {
            }
        }

        private void Prijs_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                double a = Convert.ToDouble(Aantal.Text);
                double b = Convert.ToDouble(Prijs.Text);
                double c = Convert.ToDouble(Subtotaal.Text);
                double d = Convert.ToDouble(Korting.Text);

                Subtotaal.Text = (a * b).ToString();
            }

            catch
            {
            }
        }

        private void Subtotaal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                double a = Convert.ToDouble(Aantal.Text);
                double b = Convert.ToDouble(Prijs.Text);
                double c = Convert.ToDouble(Subtotaal.Text);
                double d = Convert.ToDouble(Korting.Text);
                if (d >= 1 && d < 100)
                {
                    Totaal.Text = (c - (c / 100 * d)).ToString();
                }
                if (d <= 0)
                {
                    Totaal.Text = (c).ToString();
                }
                if (d >= 100)
                {
                    Totaal.Text = (0).ToString();
                }
            }

            catch
            {
            }
        }

        private void Korting_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                double a = Convert.ToDouble(Aantal.Text);
                double b = Convert.ToDouble(Prijs.Text);
                double c = Convert.ToDouble(Subtotaal.Text);
                double d = Convert.ToDouble(Korting.Text);

                if (d >= 1 && d < 100)
                {
                    Totaal.Text = (c - (c / 100 * d)).ToString();
                }
                if (d <= 0)
                {
                    Totaal.Text = (c).ToString();
                }
                if (d >= 100)
                {
                    Totaal.Text = (0).ToString();
                }
            }

            catch
            {
            }
        }

        private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string str;
                string titel = Titel.Text;
                string voorupdate;
                str = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(str);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(Aantal.Text);
                voorupdate = (a - b).ToString();
                if (a - b >= 0)
                {
                    Print.Enabled = true;
                    string vnaam = Voornaam.Text;
                    string anaam = Achternaam.Text;
                    string lpcd = LPCD.Text;
                    string dateColumn = dateTimePicker1.Text;
                    string firstColumn = Titel.Text;
                    string secondColumn = Aantal.Text;
                    string thirdColumn = Prijs.Text;
                    string fourthColumn = Subtotaal.Text;
                    string fifthColumn = Korting.Text;
                    string sixthColumn = Totaal.Text;
                    string[] row = { vnaam, anaam, firstColumn, secondColumn, thirdColumn, fourthColumn, fifthColumn, sixthColumn, lpcd, dateColumn };
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);



                    string cmd = "Update Album set [Actuele Voorraad]='" + voorupdate + "' where Titel='" + Titel.Text + "'";
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Evan-PC;Initial Catalog=DatabaseProject;Integrated Security=True"))
                    {

                        using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection))
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Print.Enabled = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("Fout");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Vul waarden in");
            }
        }

        private void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str;
            string str2;
            string titel;
            string voorupdate;

            titel = dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            str2 = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            str = dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            int a = Convert.ToInt32(str2);
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(str);
            voorupdate = ((a + b) - b).ToString();


            string cmd = "Update Album set [Actuele Voorraad]='" + voorupdate + "' where Titel='" + titel + "'";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Evan-PC;Initial Catalog=DatabaseProject;Integrated Security=True"))
            {

                using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }



            if (this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Index);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'databaseProjectDataSet.Album' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.albumTableAdapter1.Fill(this.databaseProjectDataSet.Album);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database_ProjectDataSet2.Album' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.albumTableAdapter.Fill(this.database_ProjectDataSet2.Album);
        }

        private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string mail = Email.Text;
                string voor = Voornaam.Text;
                string achter = Achternaam.Text;
                string adres = Adres.Text;
                string woon = Woonplaats.Text;
                string post = Postcode.Text;
                string tele = Telefoonnummer.Text;
                try
                {
                    string addcity = "If Not Exists(select * from Woonplaats where Woonplaats='@woon') Begin insert into Woonplaats (Woonplaats)" + "Values('" + woon + "')END";

                    string dataquery = "INSERT INTO Klant([E-mail], Voornaam, Achternaam, Adres, Woonplaats, Postcode, Telefoonnummer) " +
                                       "Values('" + mail + "', '" + voor + "', '" + achter + "', '" + adres + "', '" + woon + "', '" + post + "', '" + tele + "')";

                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Evan-PC;Initial Catalog=DatabaseProject;Integrated Security=True"))
                    {

                        using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(addcity, connection))
                        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(dataquery, connection))
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@woon", woon);
                            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            command.Parameters.Clear();
                            command1.Parameters.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    string dataquery = "INSERT INTO Klant([E-mail], Voornaam, Achternaam, Adres, Woonplaats, Postcode, Telefoonnummer) " +
                                       "Values('" + mail + "', '" + voor + "', '" + achter + "', '" + adres + "', '" + woon + "', '" + post + "', '" + tele + "')";

                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Evan-PC;Initial Catalog=DatabaseProject;Integrated Security=True"))
                    {

                        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(dataquery, connection))
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            command.Parameters.Clear();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Klantgegevens niet goed ingevuld");
            }

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string dataquery = "INSERT INTO Factuur VALUES(@Voornaamklant, @Achternaamklant, @Albumtitel, @Aantal, @Prijs, @Subtotaal, @Korting, @Totaal, @CDofLP, @Datuminvoeren)";

                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Evan-PC;Initial Catalog=DatabaseProject;Integrated Security=True"))
                    {

                        using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(dataquery, connection))
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Voornaamklant", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["vnaam"].Value);
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Achternaamklant", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["anaam"].Value);
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Albumtitel", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Albumtitels"].Value);
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Aantal", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Aantal2"].Value);
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prijs", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Prijs2"].Value);
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subtotaal", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Subtotaal2"].Value);
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Korting", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Korting2"].Value);
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Totaal", Convert.ToDecimal((dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Totaal2"].Value)));
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CDofLP", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["CDLP"].Value);
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datuminvoeren", Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text));
                            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            command2.Parameters.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Kan de factuur niet in de database zetten", "Fout", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By adding a breakpoint just before it shows that message on "catch", I get to see all the steps my application takes.
the Full error message is added on the bottom of my code.

Comment: I could post my whole application code if you'd need that. I'm not seeing how my code is being run twice.

Comment: Try put `command.Parameters.Clear();` in the end of command `using` block. After `command.ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: I've tried your command, Fabio, it just still gives the same error message.
Thanks for trying anyways Grant, I really don't see what causes this myself..

Comment: In your `datagridview2` do you have last empty row _New row_

Comment: Hm, no I don't have a last empty row new row.. Not that I know of if you're seeing that in the code or anything.

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error if parameter's value is `null`

So check value before passing it to `.Parameters`

```
if(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["vnaam"].Value == null)
    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Voornaamklant", DBNull.Value);
else
    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Voornaamklant", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["vnaam"].Value);
```

Comment: I have checked the values via breakpoints in the code, the values are all normal and the data _does_ get inserted.. However after the insert, it goes to the catch with the mbox because of the error. Also, I have tried the if = _NULL_ code, also with a messagebox if a _NULL_ had been found, but to no prevail.

Comment: Thank you Fabio! I am sorry this does not solve the OP's problem but I've been struggling with it for two days before I found your answer. Yes, the parameter must have the value `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me. I would try putting a break point inside the for loop and debugging it. I suspect that you have one more row returning from dataGridView2.Rows.Count than you have data. This would explain why you are seeing the values inserted into Factuur that you want to see, but you are still getting that error message.

I would put a break point at the following lines of code so you can find out what your variable i's value is when you get your exception.

```
string dataquery = "INSERT INTO Factuur VALUES(@Voornaamklant, @Achternaamklant, @Albumtitel, @Aantal, @Prijs, @Subtotaal, @Korting, @Totaal, @CDofLP, @Datuminvoeren)";

MessageBox.Show("Kan de factuur niet in de database zetten", "Fout", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

and also at the end of your for loop where you are looping through dataGridView2.Rows.

Comment: I did as you said but I really can't find it by myself, I've been struggling on this part of my application for 9 hours at the moment and I really can't find it.

Comment: Well I did that and the values that get returned all seem normal, nothing is being put in there twice and the values that are in there all get put into the database normally.. The error is just still present.